# How to abort or stop code in laravel-zero when i have multiple task?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I have multiple [laravel-zero](https://laravel-zero.com/docs/run-tasks) task like this, how to stop all task below if task A false condition?

```
$this->task("Task A", function () {
  if (!condition) {
   return false;
   exit;
   die;
  }
});

$this->task("Task B", function () {
  return true;
});
```

I want if condition in Task A false, abort all task below, i try exit, die, and $this->stop() but task in below keep running? any suggestion how i handle this?

Comment: Task A:  `if (!condition) { $this->halt("Task A failed!"); }`

Comment: @kampit thanks for answer, but task B still running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I use this approach:

```
$taskA = $this->task("Task A", function () {
  if (!condition) {
   return false;
  }
});

if(!$taskA) {
  exit;
}

$this->task("Task B", function () {
  return true;
});
```